# How to include imported class in bundle, when not directly used

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm writing my own JSX pragma and it does work pretty well except now when tying to introduce typescript JSX will not work for me. My class is being tree-shaken out or something, unless it is actively being used within a module, eg in a log statement:

```
/** @jsx V.create */
/** @jsxFrag V.Fragment */
import V, { render } from "@V"; // `@V` is in a webpack resolve.alias

render(document.getElementById("app"), <h1>hi</h1>);
```

> `external "V":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: V is not defined`

But,

```
/** @jsx V.create */
/** @jsxFrag V.Fragment */
import V, { render } from "@V"; // `@V` is in a webpack resolve.alias
console.log({ V })
render(document.getElementById("app"), <h1>hi</h1>);

^^ Works!
```

Relevant webpack object:

```
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: "babel-loader"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "paths": {
    "@V": ["js/V/index.ts"]
  }
}
```

#### How can I ensure Webpack/Typescript will not remove this import?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable tree shacking for the module V.

You can use sideEffects array to disable tree shaking

[Here the documentation of WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free)

In your package.json file

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "sideEffects": [
    "./src/some-side-effectful-file.js"
  ]
}
```